# Problem with Thinking Sphinx and Functional Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing, thinking-sphinx

this is my test (with shoulda helpers):

```
  context "searching from header" do
    setup do
      Factory(:city, :name => 'Testing It')
      ThinkingSphinx::Test.index 'city_core', 'city_delta'
      ThinkingSphinx::Test.start

      get :index,
          :query => 'Testing It'
    end

    should respond_with(:success)
    should assign_to(:results)
    should "have one city on the result" do
      assert_equal( assigns(:results).count, 1 )
      assert_kind_of( assigns(:results).first, City )
    end

    ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop
  end
```

Everything works fine except the test always say the count of the results is 0, not 1.

I have debugged this code and when the request reaches the controller, the Sphinx indexes are completely empty, even with the explicit call of index for it.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem... even tho the insertion in the database is right before the `ThinkingSphinx.index`, with transactional fixtures, after the `setup` block the records get deleted.

The solution was adding to the test the following line:

```
self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.